# Convert csv to html table using

Tags: shell, csv, html-table

How can I convert a CSV file into html table?
I got a csv file with comma "," and I want this file to convert to Html table.

Comment: Did you edit the question to remove the requirement that it be done in a shell script?  If so, please remove the tag, too,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK, you really want it only in bash?  Mission accomplished.

```
cat > input.csv
a,b,c
d,e,f
g,h,i

echo "<table>" ; while read INPUT ; do echo "<tr><td>${INPUT//,/</td><td>}</td></tr>" ; done < input.csv ; echo "</table>"
<table>
<tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr>
<tr><td>d</td><td>e</td><td>f</td></tr>
<tr><td>g</td><td>h</td><td>i</td></tr>
</table>
```

My first try used "cat" but I figured that was cheating, so I rewrote it using "while read"

Comment: I really like this solution, but: is it possible to have the first row have `<th>` tags (for table headers), and the remaining rows to have `<td>` tags?

Comment: Bash has variables, so you could set a variable to denote the first row as in firstRow=1 ; echo "<table>" ; while read INPUT ; do if [[ $firstRow = 1 ]]  ; then echo "<tr><th>${INPUT//,/</td><td>}</th></tr>" ; firstRow=0 ; else  echo "<tr><td>${INPUT//,/</td><td>}</td></tr>" ; fi ; done < input.csv ; echo "</table>"

Comment: that will only turn the first column of the first row into a table header, not the 2nd column, 3rd column, etc of the first row into a <th>... feel free to give it a test on any sized csv file, as long as it has more than 1 column of data

Answer (score 0):

XmlGrid.net has a nice tool to convert a CSV file into HTML table. Here is the link:
http://xmlgrid.net/csvToHtml.html

Comment: There's also TextFixer.com. See http://www.textfixer.com/html/csv-convert-table.php