# I can't send the data from an Excel file to an HTML file via a bash script

Tags: bash

I have a csv file containing ip addresses and I will insert all these addresses in an html page thanks to a bash script

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert csv to html table using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255449/convert-csv-to-html-table-using)

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F',' 'BEGIN{ print "<table>" } END{ print "</table>" } { print "<tr><td>"$1"</td></tr>" }' ips.csv > ips.html
```

Replace `1` with the number of the column that contains the IP addresses.